# VI - Insert buffer before

Tags: buffers

I've recently begun using buffers, rather than tabs, to sort files in `vi`. My question is, can I create a buffer such that, instead of getting this:

```
[:enew]
[:ls]
1 main.c
2 foo.txt
3 [No Name]
```

I got something like this:

```
1 main.c
2 [No Name]
3 foo.txt
```

Please note that I start on `main.c`, and have `foo.txt` in the next buffer

Comment: This isn't possible, especially since rearranging buffer numbers would break things like plugins that rely on them being consistent.

Comment: @Heptite thanks

Comment: @Heptite that would be worth posting it as an answer

Comment: This question looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Buffers and tabs (and windows) are somewhat orthogonal in Vim. When you say you're "using buffers, rather than tabs, to sort files in vim", what do you actually mean? Which commands are relevant? If you need to handle a list of files in a sequence, perhaps `:args` is more relevant here (together with `:n`, `:wn`, `:prev`, `:argdo`, etc.) but it's hard to tell based on that snippet of your question alone...

Comment: @filbranden Perhaps this is inappropriate considering the question, but can vi `:args` be manipulated? For instance, appending a file to `:args` such that `:n` eventually goes to that file?

Comment: @filbranden To answer your question, I mean the workflow I use to edit multiple files w/ vi. Had I been using tabs, `:tabn` and `:tabp` would be used. Currently I use `:bp` and `:bn` to replace them.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser In that case, I think you might like `:args` much better! The next and previous commands are shorter (`:n` and `:N` -- or `:prev` is also fine), you can control the order (e.g. `:args main.c foo.txt`), you can use wildcards (e.g. `:args **/*.c`) and `:args` is also what you get from the command-line (e.g. `$ vim main.c foo.txt` will put these two in `:args`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with buffers. Using the argument list is probably your best bet, since `:args` (see below) can edit the order of files.

Here are the equivalent commands:

- `:bn` -> `:next`
- `:bp` -> `:prev`
- `:ls` -> `:args`
- `:e` -> `:arga` & `:next`

You may want to remap, e.g.:

```
nnoremap <leader>n :next<CR>
nnoremap <leader>p :prev<CR>
...
```

Comment: All credit goes to @filbranden for this suggestion, I'm simply formatting this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, as Vim handles buffer numbers internally. They need to be predictable for various reasons, such as plugins that rely on them being consistent.

The only way to rearrange buffer numbers is to exit Vim and start it again.

Comment: This is true, however vim allows you to edit the argument list, which _doesn't_ need to be consistent. See my answer for more information